# A bady-written Scala code. How would look a well-written one? (playing with programming paradigms and techniques)

Tags: scala, oop, functional-programming, paradigms

I am a Scala newbie. The following code is my extension of the first lesson from "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" course by professor Martin Odersky from the first lesson about Rationals "Functions and Data".

I have added `opti` method that divides nominator and denominator by their greatest common divisor (`gcd`) for example makes 2/4 becomes 1/2. But just for fun I have decided to add possibility of adding automatic optimization after each call of `add` and `Sub` (forget about performance for this time). So I can write method `makeOptiAuto(Boolean): Unit` but this would require if statement in each `and`/`sub` method. So I decided to make a class called `OptimalizedRational` and that it will call `opti` at the end of each 
`and`/`sub` call.

The problem is, that I have make it as extension of my Rational class. Maybe it should be it's member (`Rational.OptimaliyedRational`)?
Secondly, I must call Rational constructor. Is that necessary in this case? In fact, I am overriding them, so Rational constructor is useless. I can call gcd like extends `Rational(gcd(x, y) / x, gcd(x, y) / y)` but it's the same value. So I have use val. Is it possible to call `Rational` constructor using `gcd` only once? What is the best way of doing that type of work?
Another problem is in `add`/`sub` methods. If I want to call method by using super, then I have `Rational` object returned, so if I want `OptimalizedRational` back, I need to use optiAuto again... Maybe I should use `asInstanceOf[Rational]` to cast it, but first, it doesn't work (an error is thrown), and second, it's slow (Java casts dynamically, if I am not wrong).

So, who would look the well-written Scala code that does what I was trying to do? Can someone sent the corrected version with some explanations?

The code:

```
object Learning {

// IMMPLEMENTATION OF `Rational` CLASS:
class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {
  def nom = x
  def denom = y

  def add(that: Rational): Rational =
    new Rational((nom*that.denom + that.nom*denom), (denom*that.denom))

  def neg: Rational =
    new Rational(-nom, denom)

  def sub(that: Rational): Rational =
    add(that.neg)

    // used by opti() and for OptimalizedRational       
    protected def gcd(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
        if (b == 0) a
        else gcd(b, a % b)

  def opti(): Rational = {
    val d = gcd(nom, denom)
    new Rational(nom / d, denom / d)
  }




  // shorthand methods: 
  def add(a: Int, b: Int): Rational = add(new Rational(a, b))
  def sub(a: Int, b:Int): Rational = sub(new Rational(a, b))

  // OptimalizedRational immplementation (between classes):
  def optiAuto() = new OptimalizedRational(nom, denom)
  def isOpti = false

  // others:
  override def toString =  { opti(); nom + "/" + denom }
}

class OptimalizedRational(x: Int, y: Int) extends Rational(x, y) {

    // constructor:
    val d = gcd(x, y)
    override def nom = x / d
    override def denom = y / d

    // basic behaviour via method overriding:
    override def add(a: Int, b: Int) = super.add(a, b).opti().optiAuto()
    override def sub(a: Int, b: Int) = super.sub(a, b).opti().optiAuto()

    // OptimalizedRational immplementation (between classes):
    def optiNoAuto() = new Rational(nom, denom)
  override def isOpti = true
}

// TESTING:

new Rational(2, 3).optiAuto().add(1, 2).sub(3, 4)
new Rational(10, 24).opti().toString()
new OptimalizedRational(10, 24).toString()
 new Rational(10, 24).toString()
}
```

Comment: From the title alone, I'd say that it's better suited for Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks, I am also Stack Exchange newbie, but as people have started answearing I will keep it the topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Rational` object is immutable. Why not simply add logic simply that optimizes the `Rational` on instantiation?

```
class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {

  protected def gcd(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
        if (b == 0) a
        else gcd(b, a % b)
  }

  //Calculate once
  val d = gcd(x, y)
  val xOverD = x / d
  val yOverD = y / d

  def nom = xOverD
  def denom = yOverD

  def add(that: Rational): Rational =
    new Rational((nom*that.denom + that.nom*denom), (denom*that.denom))

  def neg: Rational =
    new Rational(-nom, denom)

  def sub(that: Rational): Rational =
    add(that.neg)

  override def toString =  { nom + "/" + denom }
}
```

Alternatively, if you really wanted to split them up, <s>it would suffice to simply override the `nom` and `denom` methods</s> you would still need to override the methods to have a return type of `OptimalizedRational`, to do this a little more nicely, we can use an implicit conversion to convert all our `Rational`s to `OptimalizedRationals`

```
class OptimalizedRational(x: Int, y: Int) extends Rational(x, y) {

  //Calculate once
  private val d = gcd(x, y)
  private val xOverD = x / d
  private val yOverD = y / d

  override def nom = xOverD
  override def denom = yOverD

  private implicit def convert(rational: Rational): OptimalizedRational =
    new OptimalizedRational(rational.nom, rational.denom)

  override def add(that: Rational): OptimalizedRational =
    super.add(that)

  override def neg: OptimalizedRational =
    super.neg

  override def sub(that: Rational): OptimalizedRational =
    super.add(super.neg)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Hovever I still have many problems that now look abstract, but I woud like to un derstand how to solve them (calling add and substract but still operate on OptimalizedRational, and how to not repeat myself with overriding nom and denom)

Comment: See my edit. The two solutions offered are one or the other, not both (FYI). @ArturWójcik